# Upgraded to Azure SDK 2.4 - where has Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime gone?

Tags: azure, sdk

I upgraded from 2.3 to 2.4 and want to update:

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient

I found StorageClient in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.4\bin

I tried adding all of those dlls but still can't resolve a reference for ServiceRuntime. I tried looking in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.4\packages too.

Where has it gone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, it is also in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.4\bin\runtimes\base

Comment: Actually, there is no official `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` package, you should reference it from your local location, then you can set it `Copy Local=True`. +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you'll have to use nget to get a version.
This has the version 2.4 of it.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime/

Comment: I wonder why it's unofficial, are we meant to carry on having 2.3 installed?

Comment: 2.4 SDK is released see here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/04/announcing-release-of-visual-studio-2013-update-3-and-azure-sdk-2-4/

ServiceRuntime is (first link listed) is the unofficial release.