# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime analog for netstandard

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, azure-service-runtime

I'm migrate my project to netstandard. In one library I used Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime library but I can't find analog for netstandard. I need RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("storage") data.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;

...

LocalResource storage = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("storage");
string tmpFilename = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetTempFileName());
var path = Path.Combine(storage.RootPath, tmpFilename);
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921277/upgraded-to-azure-sdk-2-4-where-has-microsoft-windowsazure-serviceruntime-gone